# How to change a button style using android:background="@drawable/btn_green"

Tags: android, android-layout, button

I have found a tutorial that shows how to change the `style` of a `Button` by adding `android:background="@drawable/btn_green"` to a layout `xml` file.

I have tried adding:

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/my_button"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="@string/hello" 
    android:background="@drawable/btn_green"/>
```

I get an error in the `xml` file saying `error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'background' with value '@drawable/btn_green').`

The tutorial said that I need to `import the Backgrounds project into Eclipse by choosing the Import option from the File menu`.

I have tried going `File > Import` but I can't find anything to do with Backgrounds.

Can anyone suggest what I need to do?

Comment: I think I'm getting confused here. I thought there was like a standard library of background styles that you could add to your project. I take it you have to make your own?

Answer (score 0):

Check weather the image named "btn_green" is there in drawable-*dpi folder

Answer (score 0):

add file in btn_green in drawable folder refesh the project and clean & build

Answer (score 0):

You are having this `Error: No resource found that matches the given name` because there is no Image with name `btn_green` in `drawable` folder.

And I think you want the image should change when you click on the `Button`. For that you need to use `selector` attribute in `xml` file.For that read [this post.](http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-imagebutton-selector-example/)